# Get WIX to include references within a project

Tags: c#, winforms, wix

I'm completely new to WiX and setting up custom installers in general, so I apologise for the topic of the question!

I have a internal business application (a diary), which builds and works well, so I followed tutorials/official documentation as to adding the WiX project and referencing the Diary's csproj to it.

After then building and running this most basic version of a WiX installer, the output directory has a lone exe file, which crashes moments after loading with a File Not Found Exception.

My guess is that it has not built in either Crystal Report or NLog, both of which are referenced in my CSProj.

My question is this, how do I get WIX to include and build those project references to the output???

Any help is greatly appreciated!
/Antony

Comment: Did your WIX setup include any output files from your project? Would you be able to share the part of WIX where you include your project in the setup? This may help understand your problem better. You should also try using Orca which will help you see what is included in your final setup msi.

Comment: No one but you can know which referenced assemblies you should include in your installer nor to where they should be installed. Visual Studio's Copy To Output feature is for the convenience of debugging on the developer's machine. It could be that they are exactly what you want to install and you want them all to be installed into the same location. If that is indeed the case, then as @sttaq explains, it's easy enough to harvest that way. On the other hand, for some 3rd party components, I run their installer. You can chain and bundle installers together with a WiX Bootstrapper project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the (now defunct) Setup Project project in older versions of Visual Studio, WiX does not do automatic reference detection. You'll have to add each referenced project to the WiX project manually, just as you did for the main project.

Comment: Thank you for this, as obvious as it seems I just could not find information on getting WIX to build in other 3rd party libraries that are referenced in a (already WIX referenced) project.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately you will have to do some manual labor in order to get your projects right. I would take either of the two following approaches which require you to edit the .wixproj file:

1. Use [HeatProject](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild%5Ctask_reference%5Cheatproject.html) task. You will have to do this for all referenced projects and it will give you separate .wxs files for all of them. After this reference the component groups in those files in a feature of your WIX based setup.

   ```
   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
     <HeatProject ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" AutogenerateGuids="true" OutputFile="OutputFile.wxs" SuppressFragments="true" Project="ReferencedProject.csproj" ProjectOutputGroups="Binaries" />
   </Target>
   ```
2. Use [HeatDirectory](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild%5Ctask_reference%5Cheatdirectory.html) task. Following will pick up everything in the bin folder of your project, including any binaries for the referenced projects, and give you a single .wxs containing `UniqueComponentGroupName` which can be included in any feature.

   ```
   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <DefineConstants>BINFOLDER=PATH\TO\YourProject\bin\$(Configuration)</DefineConstants>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <HeatDirectory OutputFile="OutputFile.wxs" Directory="PATH\TO\YourProject\bin\$(Configuration)" KeepEmptyDirectories="true" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" ComponentGroupName="UniqueComponentGroupName" SuppressCom="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" GenerateGuidsNow="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" PreprocessorVariable="var.BINFOLDER" />
   </Target>
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I did try and run heat from Command line to harvest my project but it ended up doing nothing (separately from your solution)!

Comment: To add a little more to this answer, with option 2., you need to add the OutputFile (OutputFile.wxs in the example) to your Wix project like your original product.wxs file is, then you can add a ComponentGroupRef to the Feature node

Comment: @ToddK Is it possible to do that without storing the file in version control? I'd like to store the generated file as `$(IntermediateOutputPath)\Product.Generated.wxs` and then reference it somehow.

Comment: I don't check in the generated file. The project has the reference to it, and when you initially checkout of version control, it will show the warning icon that the file is missing, but once you compile, the file is there just in time.

Comment: Firetruck me, all that stuff (`DefineConstants` ... `GenerateGuidsNow` ... `SuppressRootDirectory` ... `ToolPath`) is necessary! I thought the defaults would have me covered but no. Pit of success this is not.

Comment: @sttaq which project do I put this in?  The csproj, or the wixproj?

Comment: @as9876, I think it was the wixproj file